# Image Display in ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I want to display a drawable in an imageview for a gridview,problem is that i couldnot make the image cover the full width and height of the imageView?

Answer (score 2):

Use attribute `android:scaleType="fitXY"` in your XML declaration or use `setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY)` method of ImageView class

Answer (score 1):

use this property in adapter

```
imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(150, 150));
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
imageView.setPadding(1, 1, 1, 1);
```

Comment: yes it is a medium screen ,and how do i change dimension and what??

Comment: GridView.LayoutParams(150, 150) change these properties depending on your useage..

Comment: this will make the images size small for HDPI screens ,i have to handle all screen sizes>>>